# Loop through a column of strings and NaN while avoiding NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a column called `names`:

```
names

name1
NaN
name2
NaN
```

Entries like `name1` and `name2` are of type `str`, and all the NaN entries are of type `float`, in case you needed to know.

I want to loop through this column to perform changes on the good entries while entirely leaving alone the NaN entries, as such:

```
for i in range(len(df["names"])):
    if df['names'][i].isnull() == False:
        # do stuff
```

I've tried `isnull()`, `math.isna()`, but I get errors like `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnull'` and `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` when I try to apply a lambda function instead of using a for loop.

How can I check if each row is *not* NaN, when all the good entries are strings?

Comment: What is the stuff you want to do? Can't you just delete the rows with NaN?

Comment: what do you perform exactly in the loop? would it be better to loop only on the rows not null.

Comment: Looping through a dataframe rows is usually not a good idea in general. What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if df['contact'][i] == df['contact'][i]` to identify non-`NaN` values.  This leverages the cool property that `NaN != NaN`.

Though with that said there are other probably vectorized ways to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to perform changes to the data of non NaN. You can consider this

```
df.loc[~df['name'].isna()]
```

This will help you to get the row of data that is not NaN.

Comment: There's also just `.notna()` instead of `~.isna()`